# At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided

Tags: soap, wsdl

I have defined my service on the WSDL file this way:

```
<wsdl:service name="guestbook">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:guestbookSOAP" name="guestbookSOAP">
  <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/soapguestbook"/>
</wsdl:port>
```

Still I am getting the following error message when running wsimport on it:

> At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.

Is there anything else I need to add?

Comment: I am having exactly the same thing with both JAX-WS RI 2.2.4 and 2.2.8 (both `wsimport` command line tool **and** Ant task). However note that your WSDL file is not valid. E.g. the wsdl prefix is not defined.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, in my case I trying to `wsimport` and `wsdl` from a file location and the wsdl has xml specification `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at first line, removing this  in my case the error disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your case is that the definitions element is missing, which is like a root.

WSDL has a specific structure, for which the root element should be the DEFINITIONs, under it various other elements are present like types, messages, portType, binding, services etc.

The structure is like the below:

```
<definitions> 
    <types> data type definitions........ </types>
    <message>  definition of the data being communicated.... </message>
    <portType>   set of operations...... </portType>
    <binding>   protocol and data format specification.... </binding>
</definitions>
```

For the meaning of each WSDL element look into the link: 
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_wsdl.asp